# ASP.NET/VB...users log on and see the own data only?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to make a system that stores employees details...name address etc.

I would like the users to be able to log on, see and change their own details only.

Is this possible is asp.net and if so how?

I'm really new at this so if you could keep answers as simple as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good starting point for your research...

Check out [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).  This is a good, out of the box, solution for storing basic "member" information (login/password/name/etc.).  It will give you a good starting point for handling user authentication and building out ways for users to manager their info.

I usually use the SQL Membership Provider.  Have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingthesqlmembershipprovider) for good instructions on how to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the asp.net membership system, a walk-through can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx